# Obtain a segment of Polyline which was clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, leaflet, react-leaflet

In my app I have:

```
<MapContainer {...opts} scrollWheelZoom>
  <>..</>
  <Polyline eventHandlers={{ click: e => { console.log('line clicked', e.sourceTarget) }, }} positions={positonArrat}/>}
</MapContainer>
```

Each polyline consists of N straight line sections.

How can I get the segment of polyline which was clicked without using [rocket science](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018003/which-segment-of-a-polyline-was-clicked)?

Another option would be to replace a single polyline with mulitple lines, so that each click would get a single result, but a out-of-box solution would be nice...

Comment: I would split the polyline into sections and calculate the distance between the clicked point and the sections.

Comment: that would be an overkill: I don't need to calculate distances, I already know that the point belongs to the polyline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [simple math](https://www.math-only-math.com/straight-line-in-two-point-form.html) and the onClick-function looks like:

```
const TOLERANCE = 3

onPolylineClick = e => {
  const { x, y } = e.layerPoint
  const parts = e.target._parts[ 0 ] // some undocumented shit
  let prev = parts[ 0 ]
  const section = parts.slice( 1, parts.length ).findIndex( p => {
    try{
      // check if in bounds
      if( !( Math.min( prev.x, p.x ) <= x <= Math.max( prev.x, p.x ) && 
             Math.min( prev.y, p.y ) <= y <= Math.max( prev.y, p.y ) ) ) return false
      const yCalc = ( x - prev.x ) * ( p.y - prev.y ) / ( p.x - prev.x ) + prev.y
      return Math.abs( y - yCalc ) < TOLERANCE
    }finally{
      prev = p
    }
  })
  this.setState( { selectedSection:section } )
}
```

It sets the index of the 1st point of the matching section in `state`.

Then to visualize the selected section I show an orange polyline of 2 points on top:

```
<MapContainer {...opts} scrollWheelZoom>

  <Polyline eventHandlers={{ click:this.onPolylineClick }} positions={points} />}
  
  {-1 !== selectedSection && 
     <Polyline color="orange" positions={points.slice( selectedSection, selectedSection + 2 )}/>}

</MapContainer>
```

Comment: Is this working for you?  You have to be careful using `._parts`, as it may change with every zoom level if `smoothFactor` is set, or when part of the polyline is out of frame, unless you specify [`noClip`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#polyline-noclip).  I had started my answer with using the `._parts` prop, but ran into problems because of this

Comment: yeah, it works. As I understood, the `_parts` as well as `layerPoint` contain coords in pixels rather than latlng, so the zoom level and the rest do not have any influence

Comment: yes they do contain the associated pixel coordinates, but what's not documented is that the `_parts` prop is updated with every zoom / pan event to include only what's in frame, or to smooth out the polyline with lower zoom levels.  I learned that the hard way.  if you end up getting wierd or inconsistent results, keep that in mind

Comment: @SethLutske the only thing I noticed is, that on map's boundaries the x and y  are turning negative and that can produce wrong results for zoomed-in partially visible sections, which is actually not critical and in this case I just display a warning

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to do this, though nothing built-in / native to leaflet, as far as I know.  Redrawing your polyline as a series of unisegmental polylines is one way, as you mentioned.  You seem to have this plan of attack laid out in your mind already, so let's discuss another way.

This does not involve rocket science, but it does involve math.  Your comment mentioned that you don't need to calculate distances as you already know that the point belongs to the polyline.  Just knowing that the point belongs to the polyline is not enough.  You need to know the shortest distance between the clicked point and each segment of the polyline.  So you need distances.

[leaflet-geometryutil](https://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.GeometryUtil/) offers some useful functions.  The following code uses the `distanceSegment` function to get the shortest distance between a point and a unisegmental polyline.   Let's look at the `onClick':

```js
eventHandlers={{
  click: (e) => {
    const closest = getSegment(e.latlng, e.sourceTarget);
    setResults([...results, closest]);
  }
}}
```

On click, we pass the `latlng` and the `L.polyline` instance to `getSegment`.  `geSegment` returns an object which contains the index of the `L.polyline._latlngs` array associated with the shortest distance to the clicked point, the distance, and for convenience, an array of that `latlng` and the one after it:

```js
function getSegment(latlng, polyline) {

  // get layerpoint of user click
  const latlngs = polyline._latlngs;
  let segments = [];

  // get segments of polyline
  // calculate distances from point to each polyline
  for (let i = 0; i < latlngs.length - 1; i++) {
    const pointToLineDistance = GeoUtil.distanceSegment(
      polyline._map,
      latlng,
      latlngs[i],
      latlngs[i + 1]
    );

    segments.push({
      index: i,
      pointToLineDistance,
      segment: [latlngs[i], latlngs[i + 1]]
    });
  }

  // sort segments by shortest distance
  segments.sort((a, b) =>
    a.pointToLineDistance < b.pointToLineDistance ? -1 : 1
  );

  // return first entry, which has shortest distance
  return segments[0];
}
```

Since we're using react-leaflet, I used a `useState` function to capture any segments clicked, and then render them to the map:

```js
{results.map((r, i) => (
  <Polyline key={`polyline-${i}`} positions={r.segment} color="green" />
))}
```

### [Working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/polyline-click-get-segment-geoutil-v0ufe)

Click on the polyline in the sandbox.  The closest segment to the click will be identified, saved to state, and rendered in green.

Other than your method of breaking the polyline up, or doing some math, I'm not sure how else this could be done.  I'm sure you can come up with some variations