# Changing the color of a Leaflet map polyline as I navigate from point A to B

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, openstreetmap, shapefile, react-leaflet

I'm working on a project where I'm using Leaflet to create a map. I've defined a path from point A to B, and it's currently colored yellow. However, I want to change the color of the traveled path to blue when I start navigation. How can I achieve this?

Here are some additional details about my project:

I'm using Leaflet to display the map.
I've already defined the initial path from point A to B with a yellow polyline.
I need to dynamically change the color of the path to blue from my starting point to my current location when the user starts navigation.
I would appreciate any guidance or code examples on how to implement this color change in Leaflet as the user progresses along the route

Comment: Can you check this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65082167/obtain-a-segment-of-polyline-which-was-clicked

Once you get the segment from the beginning to the cursor location, you can change its color with:

 polyline.setStyle({ color: 'blue'});
 polyline.redraw();  

So just put the line on the map with a zIndex greater than the base polyline.